# Django: How to set a field's default value to the value of a field in a parent model

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have the following model

```
class Sammich(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ratio_of_cheese_to_meat = models.FloatField(default=0.3)
```

I'd like be able to create a new model that has a field which pulls its default from ratio_of_cheese_to_meat of the Sammich class

```
class DeliSammich(models.Model):
    sammich = models.ForiegnKey(Sammich)
    type_of_meat = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type_of_cheese = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ratio_of_cheese_to_meat = models.FloatField(default=Sammich.objects.get(pk=sammich.id).ratio_of_cheese_to_meat)
```

Which isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to [override the model's `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)  and get the default:

```
class DeliSammich(models.Model):
    sammich = models.ForeignKey(Sammich)
    type_of_meat = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type_of_cheese = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ratio_of_cheese_to_meat = models.FloatField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.ratio_of_cheese_to_meat:
            self.ratio_of_cheese_to_meat = self.sammich.ratio_of_cheese_to_meat
        super(DeliSammich, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could solve that using a *Global Variable*.  If you used a *Global Variable*, your `models.py` would look like this:

```
DEFAULT_SAMMICH = 0.3

class Sammich(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ratio_of_cheese_to_meat = models.FloatField(default=DEFAULT_SAMMICH)

class DeliSammich(models.Model):
    sammich = models.ForiegnKey(Sammich)
    type_of_meat = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type_of_cheese = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ratio_of_cheese_to_meat = models.FloatField(default=DEFAULT_SAMMICH)
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve my problem.  If the user sets the ratio_of_cheese_to_meat in a Sammich instance to something like 0.5, I want the default ratio_of_cheese_to_meat for a DeliSammich instance that is tied to the Sammich instance to be 0.5.

Comment: @Brian point well taken.  The above answer by *alecxe* is the correct django way of handling that.